# Rendering math functions in Android with JLatexMath

Tags: android, math, android-imageview

Im' trying to render and display in real time a math functions into my android app... I founded some libraries and i'm trying to use [JLatexMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/). I've created a ImageView into my layout but i dont't know how to render the image and display it. Anyone can help me?